S3 Auto Copy feature in Redshift
For S3 AUTO COPY, how to handle following situations?

Automatic Notification on failure of AUTO COPY job

Re-attempt on failure due to
a. Structural errors- Column size issue/table permission issues/New column in file which is not in table.
b. Table does not exist.
c. Target DB connection error.


In this cases, does it require manual intervention to retry particular file?
How auto copy will handle this? Does it automatically retry the same error file again for 'x' number of times (OR) re-tries for some specific duration (OR) directly skips and someone will have to manually required to do this using command.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Kindly provide more information on this.

So in order to monitor the AUTO COPY : Redshift AUTO COPY integrates with Amazon EventBridge to capture ingestion events, including failures. You can set up an EventBridge rule to detect failure events and send SNS or trigger a Lambda. You just need to ensure logging is enabled for your Redshift cluster with the parameter enable_user_activity_logging set to true.
Column Size Issue or New Columns in File - this needs a manual intervention to:
1 - Update schemas in the target database.

2 - Adjust data file formatting or transformations.

You can use the Redshift AUTO schema evolution to get rid of schema errors, but if some type is not supported you'll need to manual update the schema also. And when an issue occurs in this step Redshift logs the error and skips the problematic file. So, when you fix the file schema, you need to manual retry the job using COPY command.
Permission issue - you can just retry after resolve the issue and add the missed permissions.
Table not exists - this needs a manual intervention to :
1 - Create the target table.

2 - Map the incoming file schema to the table.

and for this, you can integrate a Lambda function to check if the table is there or no before the AUTO COPY job, and if it's not there, then the Lambda will create it using some predefined schema and trigger the AUTO COPY job afterwards.
Target DB Connection Error - Redshift automatically retries for transient issues up to a default threshold. and you can also implement a retry mechanism with exponential backoff. if it persists you need also manually to fix it and retry the job.
